# Oracle UROWID or SEQUENCE

Tags: oracle10g, identity, rowid, surrogate-key

I need to create a surrogate identity key for some intermediate tables used in a stored procedure in Oracle.  I found that ROWID inserted into a UROWID column works well but this is not the correct way in older versions of Oracle (before 10g) -- using SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL is.  SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL is a 2 step process and uses up memory/storage (full table scan) whereas with the ROWID way you just save the address and you're done. (like IDENTITY in SQL)
I want to use ROWID as the identity key.  Is it OK for me to do this?

Comment: Why would correctly using a sequence ever cause a full table scan?!?

Comment: I do mostly INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO table(...) SELECT ... FROM; I like to have the data ordered by the compound PK columns that the identity PK replaces (as a surrogate) so that later on I can order by the Id generated from the seq.nextVal.  Makes debugging the intermediate table data left over after the stored procedure executes easy too.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be on the save side, this is how pros use sequences:

```
insert into master_table(id, x, y, z) values seq_master.nextval, :x, :y, :z;

insert into detail_table(master_id, a, b) values (seq_master.currval, :a, :b);
insert into detail_table(master_id, a, b) values (seq_master.currval, :c, :d);
...
```

I would prefer sequences any day over ROWIDs.

Comment: I'm doing a direct load insert of the data. Direct Load Insert only works for INSERT INTO .. SELECT .... Inserts using the VALUES clause will use conventional insert. http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/direct%20path.html